# This release does not add or remove any app bundles

Tags: developer-console

I can't seem to find any information on this issue. Does anyone know how to resolve this? This is my first time publishing anything, in the past 8 years.
[image]

Comment: Are you uploading a new app/bundle? The error is basically telling you your release won't have any effect since it is not adding or removing an artefact.